# Uninitialized constant inside controller namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to solve the following issue but I just can't get my head around the autoloading in Rails yet. I have the following controller located in **app/api/v1/registration_controller.**

```
class Api::V1::RegistrationController < ApplicationController
   include ::Foo::Bar

   def index
   end
 end
```

And the following module/class in **app/foo/bar.rb:**

```
module Foo
  class Bar
     def some_method
     end
  end
end
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
uninitialized constant Foo
```

I'm trying to get my head around this and already searched Stack Overflow for solutions, but I wasn't able to find the right one. If the solution is already written down elsewhere, please close this topic.

Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails autoloader searches a number of paths to try to locate constants - `app/` isn't one of them. You can add it by appending it in application.rb, like:

```
config.autoload_paths << File.join(config.root, "app")
```

Or just move `foo/bar.rb` into `lib/`, which is already in the loader path.

Comment: This works, thanks!! Is it a best practice to move those kind of files into the lib folder instead of the app folder?

Comment: Yes, I typically keep them in lib. If I'm adding a new class of things I want under app/ (like `decorators`), I'll add app/decorators to the load path, but in general, bespoke stuff goes into lib.